# C pointers - pass by value

Tags: c, pointers

I want to know why is it that when i call readF() and have it return the buffer pointer and i print the buffer in main() it prints the actual data and not the memory address? I am returning the address and not the actual data correct? In my main i have a pointer that points to what gets returned, which is just what the buffer pointer in readF() points to.

```
char *readF(){

char *buffer=NULL;

//allocate memory to contain the string plus null terminator
buffer=malloc((sizeof(char)*4)+1);
//fill memory with string Hello plus terminator

return buffer;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
char *buffer;
buffer=readF();
printf("%s", buffer);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You print the actual data inside the buffer because you use the `%s` format specified in your `printf` statement. This tells `printf` to assume the pointer it receives, `buffer` in this case for the first specifier, is a pointer to a NULL-terminated character string, so it prints the string.

If you want to print the address use the `%p` format specifier

You're correct when you say the `readF` function is returning the memory address. It returns the memory address of the first byte of the buffer, ie a pointer to the buffer you allocate.

Note: at the end of your function you should really `free(buffer)` too :)

Comment: so because i specify "%s" it automatically knows to dereference that pointer to print the data?

Comment: yes, that's right :) Specifically printf will treat the pointer as a poitner to a NULL terminated character string. It will keep printing characters until it hits a NULL character

Answer (score 1):

To print the address you need `%p` specifier.
Change

```
printf("%s", buffer);
```

to

```
printf("%p", (void *)buffer);
```